# Perl read file line by line output SHA256

Tags: perl, hash, sha256, sha, sha2

I'm trying to read a text file line by line and then printing out the SHA256 value in terminal afterwards.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

...

use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {

    print $line;
    print sha256_hex($line), "\n";

    print "Next", "\n";

}
close $fh;
```

Sample output:

```
test
f2ca1bb6c7e907d06dafe4687e579fce76b37e4e93b7605022da52e6ccc26fd2
Next
```

When I tried using `sha256_hex('test');` instead of `sha256_hex($line);` the hash value is `9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08`.

What did I do wrong? I am a newbie in perl, so excuse if it is something silly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you read a line from a file using `<$fh>` the line end from the input is included in the result. Thus, what you did was to hash `test\n` instead of `test`:

```
use Digest::SHA 'sha256_hex'; 
print sha256_hex("test\n"),"\n"; # f2ca1bb6c7e907d06dafe4687e579fce76b37e4e93b7605022da52e6ccc26fd2
print sha256_hex("test"),"\n";   # 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08
```

Comment: Thanks!```chomp $line;``` before printing the SHA256 hash solves it.